# Installation is incomplete - Magento 2.6.1

Tags: apache, magento, installation, macos-sierra

I've having a hard time with this and i've tried everything. I've read tons of other peoples resolutions and tried. This is what I have going on.

local development
Mac Os x Sierra

I've installed and run everything in this location

/Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/

I've used these tutorials to get everything up and running.
https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-macos-sierra/

Everything seems to work fine up until it gets to the 67% install and then it stops.

There was a suggestions to uncomment these lines in my httpd.conf file

LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

But when I do that my localhost stops working even after I restart.

I've literally been spending an entire day trying to get this installed on my local machine.

Can someone help me?

Comment: ensure that AllowOverride is set to All within the <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents"> section.

Comment: @ahses I'm not sure what you mean by this? what file do I need to change?

Comment: the file which you using libphp5